# Python: if...elif isnt returning proper results

Tags: python, selenium, if-statement

As part of a practice project me and a friend are writing a script to make the Asset Management Software easier. We're automating filling in the required fields and pressing all the buttons required to check out for example a phone. 
After searching for a specific device there are two options:
- device is found and is available, thus can be checked out
- device is found but not available, thus can't be checked out

To achieve this we wrote an if-statement, checking for the 'Checkout' or 'Checkin' and accordingly gives us the next options.

We have tried all kinds of things with indentations, reversing the order of the statements, ... The script just never seems to get to the 'else' point. When current status is 'checkin' it gives the messagebox asking to start over, but when the current status is 'checkout' it never actually prints the '5000'.

We've also tried having an elif instead of else, specifying: elif browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="Check this item out"]'):
But even then, it never actually comes to the point of going into the else.

```
if browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="Check this item in so it is available for re-imaging, re-issue, etc."]'):
    print("1")
    statusResult = tk.messagebox.askquestion('Device not available', 'Device has been checked out already. Do you wish to start over?', icon='warning')
    if statusResult == 'yes':
        print("2")
    elif statusResult == 'no':
        print("3")
else:
    print("5000")
```

When status is 'checkin', the messagebox needs to popup asking to start over (this is working). When status is 'checkout', the script needs to move to the else-statement and print 5000 as an example.

Comment: who is your website populated? Is the title dynamic? In the view source can you find that xpath both times yourself?

Comment: As long as the element exists, it won't go to the else.

Comment: For now I'm using a demo asset management system, which can be found and viewed on https://demo.snipeitapp.com 
I can indeed find both xpaths myself manually, and even when I tried "browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="Check this item out"]').click()" without having them in an if-statement, they also work. It's just from the second I place it in the if-statement, it somehow stops working

Comment: Try printing status result before going to the if else statement. This isn't a problem with if else, this is a problem with your code

Comment: Even if the element doesn't exist the code won't enter the `else` block, `find_element_` returns the element or throws `NoSuchElementException`. Use `find_elements_` instead.

Comment: change your if to this `if len(browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@title="Check this item in so it is available for re-imaging, re-issue, etc."]')) == 0`

Comment: Both above comments were indeed the solution (by Guy and Valga). I came across this but didnt really understand why it would make a difference in actually functioning. I guess I have some reading up to do in the use cases for 'element' or 'elements'. Thank you to everyone :)

P.S. I can't find how to mark an answer as accepted, don't see any option for it. Maybe because it's a new account?

Answer (score 0):

The `find_element_by_*` methods don't return boolean.. You can't use them with the if statement like your example does.   They will either return a `WebElement` (when found), or raise a `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException` (when not found).

```
try:
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="Check this item in so it is available for re-imaging, re-issue, etc."]'):
    print('found')
except NoSuchElementException:
    print('not found')
```